# ThreadLocal for ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Can someone please tell me why threadlocal.get() gives me null when i start a thread using ScheduledExecutorService ?

```
 public class ThreadTest extends ParentClassThread
  {
    private static ScheduledFuture<?> periodicFuture;
    private static ScheduledExecutorService ex;

    public ThreadTest(){
        ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        periodicFuture = ex.schedule(this, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {
            System.out.println("Thread started");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            ThreadLocal local = new ThreadLocal();
            System.out.println(local.get());
        }catch(Exception e){

        }finally {
            ex.shutdown();
        }

      }
   }
```

Comment: updated the question... please have a look

Comment: Without setting the threadlocal you are trying to access using get method.

Comment: That is not how you typically use ThreadLocal; what are you trying to achieve? This looks like a XY problem

Comment: my bad... I couldnt understand a simple thing.... Accepted below answer...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ThreadLocal<String> local = new ThreadLocal<String>();
local.set("String");
System.out.println(local.get());
```

You need to set something in ThreadLocalVariable and then retrieve it. Initially, ThreadLocal is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Because specified ThreadLocal variable is empty.
You need to either set a value or specify an initial value.

```
ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> "initial value");
```

or

```
ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>(); // now holding null
threadLocal.set("value"); //now holding "value"
```

If you do not set a value, ThreadLocal holds null as default.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize thread local outside of method run. You only initialize it once and then using .set() and .get() from inside threads. Do not use multiple instances of thread local.